# Web2py: how to config menu.py to add link to an external link

Tags: python, web-applications, web2py

I have just started learning the web2py framework from example, I saw that when the menu.py is configured as following:

```
response.menu = [
    (T('Index'), False, URL('default','index'),[]),]
```

Then there will be an item show in the menu bar, linking to:

> %website%/%application name%/default/index

So here is the question, how to config the menu.py file so as to add an item to link to an external link? Say: www.google.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third item in the tuple can be any URL, not just one generated by the web2py `URL()` function. So, you can do:

```
response.menu = [(T('Index'), False, 'http://www.google.com')]
```

Comment: Any chance for a _target='blank' to sneak into the machinery at this point?

Comment: The third item in the tuple can be any HTML helper, in which case, it will be rendered in lieu of a link with the first item as its text. So, you can do: `response.menu = [('', False, A('Menu Item', _target='_blank', _href='www.example.com'))]`.